# How to make Elevated Button with Gradient background?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create an Elevated button with gradient background, But it provides some parameters that do not fit it well, and May you know that after Flutter 2.0 version most of the Button classes have been deprecated such as Raised Button, Flat Button, ... etc

```
ElevatedButton(
child: Text('Woolha.com'),
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
  primary: Colors.teal,
  onPrimary: Colors.white,
  onSurface: Colors.grey,
),
onPressed: () {
  print('Pressed');
},
)
```

Is there anyway to create `ElevatedButton` with gradient background?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

#### Screenshot (Null safe)

[image]

---

**Create this class** (customizable)

```dart
class MyElevatedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final BorderRadiusGeometry? borderRadius;
  final double? width;
  final double height;
  final Gradient gradient;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;
  final Widget child;

  const MyElevatedButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.child,
    this.borderRadius,
    this.width,
    this.height = 44.0,
    this.gradient = const LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.cyan, Colors.indigo]),
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final borderRadius = this.borderRadius ?? BorderRadius.circular(0);
    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: gradient,
        borderRadius: borderRadius,
      ),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: borderRadius),
        ),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

Use it like a regular `ElevatedButton`:

```dart
MyElevatedButton(
  width: double.infinity,
  onPressed: () {},
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
  child: Text('SIGN IN'),
)
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't give the way that I want, it adds extra space to the background.

Comment: I've updated the code!

Comment: Well , gradient done but the effect gone while touch on button and click it

Comment: @QutbuddinBohra The effect you are talking about is called ripple effect and as you can see in the screenshot, ripple effect is there. The button resembles everything a regular `ElevatedButton` supports.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad , brother , as above code ripple effect gone because of gradient used in Container and Elevated button color transparent, 
So i want to know how we can used ripple effect with gradient in ElevatedButton ?

Comment: @QutbuddinBohra Did you run my code? You can see in the screenshot that the ripple effect is there. If you're not seeing it in your code, please share your code.

Comment: @QutbuddinBohra The order of the parent-child matters. Maybe you have the ElevatedButton as the parent and Container as the child, which causes the ripple effect to not appear. The Container has to be the parent to see the ripple effect.

Answer (score 19):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RoundedButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String buttonText;
  final double width;
  final Function onpressed;

  RoundedButtonWidget({
    required this.buttonText,
    required this.width,
    required this.onpressed,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black26, offset: Offset(0, 4), blurRadius: 5.0)
          ],
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            stops: [0.0, 1.0],
            colors: [
              Colors.deepPurple.shade400,
              Colors.deepPurple.shade200,
            ],
          ),
          color: Colors.deepPurple.shade300,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        ),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
              ),
              minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(width, 50)),
              backgroundColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
              // elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(3),
              shadowColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
                  ),
          onPressed: () {
            onpressed();
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 10,
              bottom: 10,
            ),
            child: Text(
              buttonText,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                // fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment(-0.95, 0.0),
                    end: Alignment(1.0, 0.0),
                    colors: [const Color(0xff667eea), const Color(0xff64b6ff)],
                    stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                  ),
                ),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.transparent,
                      onSurface: Colors.transparent,
                      shadowColor: Colors.transparent,),

                  onPressed: (){},

                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Log in',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: textFontFamilySegoeUI,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                        letterSpacing: -0.3858822937011719,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Container(
                    width: 1120.w,
                    height: 180.h,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [Color(0xFF0379C6), Color(0xFF1298EF)]),
                        
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.r),
                        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(16, 142, 233, 0.57),
                              blurRadius: 13)
                        ]),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                            Colors.transparent), 
                      ),
                      onPressed: () => setState(() {
                        // _launched = _makePhoneCall('tel:$_phone');
                      }),
                      child: Text(
                        'Submit',
                        style:
                            TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 64.sp),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

[botao](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPJHz.png)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Priscila Dev'),
  ),
  body: Center(
      child: Container(
    width: 300,
    height: 100,
    decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
      shape: StadiumBorder(),
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.orange, Colors.green],
      ),
    ),
    child: MaterialButton(
      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
      shape: const StadiumBorder(),
      child: const Text(
        'ENCERRAR[enter image description here][1]',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        print('Hello!');
      },
    ),
  )),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 6.0, 10.0, 6.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient:
          LinearGradient(colors: [Color(0xff3b8594), Color(0xff59a6b6)]),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
  child: Text(
    'View more',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
  ),
)
```

Result

[image]